# Bazaar(Iranian Android Market) in Update Checking error

Tags: android

For Update Checking in my app use Bazaar(Iranian Android Market) API.

All things are right but when app is start i got this error in log :

[image]

any thing is here 
https://developers.cafebazaar.ir/fa/docs/bazaar-services-update-check/
but dont work!!

Comment: please post your code add in side of question. please check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: we need to see your codes. probably you think All things are right. but in 99.9% of problems, things are not right

Answer (score 0):

i solved problem!!!
problem not in codes but is from bazaar market!

Comment: what was the problem?